# SQL SUM Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum

I wrote the following query to calculate the sum.  How can also have this query display each individual record that its summing up?

```
SELECT 'BEN' + CardCode, SUM(PayAmount) 
FROM BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN BENSALEM.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' 
AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
AND Checked = 'Y'
GROUP BY CardCode
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server?? 2000? 2005? 2008? 2008 R2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the WITH ROLLUP clause in your SELECT statement. Depending on which type of SQL server you're using there's a few different syntaxes.

MS SQL Server 2000/2005 would look like this:

```
SELECT 'BEN' + CardCode, SUM(PayAmount) 
FROM BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN BENSALEM.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' AND T5.Canceled = 'N' AND Checked = 'Y'
GROUP BY CardCode WITH ROLLUP
```

This will return the individual records, plus an additional record where the first field is NULL and the second field is the SUM(). Note that you can do this with more levels of grouping, and it will include sub-totals as well with the appropriate fields set to NULL.

SQL Server 2008 has a more ANSI-compliant syntax that does the same thing:

```
SELECT 'BEN' + CardCode, SUM(PayAmount) 
FROM BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN BENSALEM.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' AND T5.Canceled = 'N' AND Checked = 'Y'
GROUP BY ROLLUP(CardCode)
```

From what I remember, MySQL uses the first form and Oracle uses the second form.

EDIT:

My query doesn't actually give the results you want; ROLLUP() works by taking the existing aggregate function and performing it recursively on broader and broader groups. What you want is to have a series of rows with no aggregate function and apply the aggregate once.

You can get this effect using a COMPUTE BY clause but those were deprecated long ago, and the results are messy, so I'd avoid them. (Check MSDN for details if you really want to.)

The easiest way to accomplish your goal is to find a way to make each record unique, such as including a primary key field, so that PayAmount and SUM(PayAmount) produce the same result, then do your rollup.

```
SELECT IdEntry, 'BEN' + CardCode, SUM(PayAmount) 
FROM BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN BENSALEM.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' AND T5.Canceled = 'N' AND Checked = 'Y'
GROUP BY ROLLUP(CardCode, IdEntry)
```

This will give you a result that looks something like this:

```
1     BEN1234  1000
2     BEN1234  2000
3     BEN1234  1000
NULL  BEN1234  4000
4     BEN4567  1500
5     BEN4567  1500
6     BEN4567  1000
NULL  BEN4567  4000
NULL  NULL     8000
```

Let us know if that'll work for you.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm using SQL Server 2008, but for some reason when I ran the second query it said that 'ROLLUP is not a recognized built-in function name.  When I ran the first query, it didn't give me any errors, but it didn't return the individual records that are being grouped, only the one row with the grouped sum and another one with the NULL in the first column.  Like this:

     BENV5649         1330.010000
     NULL         1330.010000

Comment: If you upgraded your database from 2005 it's probably in 2005 compatibility mode, and you'd need to use SQL 2005 syntax. But you're correct that the query doesn't return the results you actually want. I'll edit my answer to include more detauls.

Comment: @Martin if I'm reading his question right, he wants to see all 4 rows (2 VISA and 2 AMEX) plus subtotals, which my original query didn't do.

Comment: Yep. Realise that after I saw your edit. Revised version http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/97919/. And I think the OP wants just one summary row so they might need `GROUP BY ROLLUP((CardCode, IdNumber))`

Comment: I had to modify the query slightly to fit my version and data:  Here it is:  
SELECT PymNum, 'BEN' + CardCode, SUM(InvPayAmnt) 
FROM BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN BENSALEM.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' AND T5.Canceled = 'N' AND Checked = 'Y'
GROUP BY CardCode, PymNum WITH ROLLUP

Here are the results:

0 BENV5649 -35.000000
1 BENV5649 -85.000000
2 BENV5649 215.000000
3 BENV5649 1235.010000
NULL BENV5649 1330.010000
NULL NULL 1330.010000

Comment: Is it possible to have the summary display once?  And one more thing.. its ok if this is not possible - but is there a way to have the summary be on top of the detailed records?

Comment: Not with the built-in SELECT clauses, at least that I know of. What you want to accomplish is most easily done using a sequence of SQL statements: SELECT into a temp table with ROLLUP, DELETE whatever intermediate summary rows you don't want, then SELECT from the temp table in whatever order you want.

Comment: Can you give an example of using a temp table?

Answer (score 1):

You can't aggregate and not aggregate in the same query, but you can combine the two:

```
SELECT 'BEN' + CardCode, SUM(PayAmount) 
FROM BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN BENSALEM.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' 
AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
AND Checked = 'Y'
GROUP BY CardCode

UNION ALL  -- combine the two
SELECT 'BEN' + CardCode, PayAmount  -- not aggregating here, this will return all rows
FROM BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3
INNER JOIN BENSALEM.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' 
AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
AND Checked = 'Y'
```

**edit**: and since you specified MS SQL Server in your comments, Martin points out you can use `ROLLUP` to do it in one query.  [Read the MSDN doc on `ROLLUP` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Pretty sure there is a `ROLLUP` solution to this.

Comment: @Martin was not familiar with `ROLLUP`, will add some info to my answer about it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'BEN' + CardCode, BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3.*,
       SUM(PayAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CardCode) sum_PayAmount
  FROM BENSALEM.dbo.PWZ3
 INNER JOIN BENSALEM.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = IdEntry
 WHERE T5.PmntDate = '4/1/2011' 
   AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
   AND Checked = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a second query to retrieve the data you want.  When you use a `GROUP BY`, you will only retrieve one row for each unique value on the group by column.  Usually any field you add to the select list will return the value of the first row in the group.

Obviously aggregate functions like `SUM` return the result of the function for all values in the group.